# Java, chat, server sends, client receives ok but not other way around. Video on youtube to watch issue

Tags: java

The scenario is, as seen on the video on youtube,

```
 http://youtu.be/5OwXqnZ64rE
```

is that while the server chat window does send the messages and the client gets them and shows them, it doesn't work the other way around.

Here are the three classes:

```
Server:

package backend;

import frontend.Gui;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Natalochka
 */
public class Server implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private ServerSocket ss;
    private Socket s;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;    
    private Gui servertalkstogui;    

    public Server(Gui in ) {
        servertalkstogui = in;

    }    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {       
        if(ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getCreate()){
            servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append("This is the server: " + "\n");
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();          
        }

        if(ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getButton()){            
            String linea = servertalkstogui.getTextField().getText();
            servertalkstogui.getTextField().setText("");
            this.writeLine(linea);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {        
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
            s = ss.accept();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
            this.readLine();         

        } catch (IOException e) {           
            try { 
                this.closeServer();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                System.out.println("se jodio");
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            e.getLocalizedMessage();        
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
    }

    public void writeLine(String linea){        
        try {            
            oos.writeObject(linea);
            servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append("\n I say: " + linea);            
        } catch (IOException e) {            
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }        
    }

    public void readLine() throws InterruptedException{        
        try {
            while(true){                
             Object aux = ois.readObject();
             if(aux != null && aux instanceof String){                 
              servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append("Client says: " + (String)aux + "\n");

             }
         }

      } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

   }

}


    public void closeServer() throws IOException{

        try {
             oos.close();
             s.close();
             ss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.addSuppressed(e);

        }

    }

}

CLIENT

package backend;

import frontend.Gui;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



/**
 *
 * @author Natalochka
 */
public class Client implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private Socket s;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private Gui clienttalkstogui;


    public Client(Gui in){    
    clienttalkstogui = in;

}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {      

        // to connect to the socket that the Server opened
        if(ae.getSource() == clienttalkstogui.getConnect()){            
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();         
        }

       // to obtain and send whatever was typed in the text field   
        if(ae.getSource() == clienttalkstogui.getButton()){            
            String linea = clienttalkstogui.getTextField().getText();
            this.writeLine(linea);            
        }

     }    

    @Override
     public void run() {

        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 9999);            
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
            clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append("Conected to port" + "\n");
            this.readLine();

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

      public void writeLine(String linea){        
        try { 
            // to send it to the server
            oos.writeObject(linea);
            // to have it displayed on the client window too
            clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append(linea);

        } catch (IOException e) { 
            //this.closeClient();
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }


    public void readLine() throws InterruptedException{        
        try {
            while(true){                
             Object aux = ois.readObject();
             if(aux != null && aux instanceof String){                 
              clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append("Server says: " + (String)aux + "\n");
             }
         }

      } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

   }

}  

   /*

    public void closeClient()
    {
        try {
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }



    }    

*/    



}
```

GUI

```
package frontend;

import backend.Client;
import backend.Server;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Natalochka
 */
public class Gui extends JFrame{    

    private JMenuBar bar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem connect, create, exit;

    private JTextArea areachat;
    private JTextField campochat;
    private JButton botonchat;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    /*WE CREATE INSTANTIATED OBJECTS OF CLASSES INTERACTING WITH THE GUI*/
    Server servidor = new Server(this);
    Client cliente = new Client(this);



    /*CREATING THE CONSTRUCTOR*/

    public Gui(){

        super("CHAT WINDOW");
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /*INSTANTIATE THE OBJECTS*/
        bar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        connect = new JMenuItem("Conectar");
        create  = new JMenuItem("Crear");
        exit    = new JMenuItem("Salir");

        areachat  = new JTextArea();
        campochat = new JTextField(20);
        botonchat = new JButton("Send");
        scroll = new JScrollPane(areachat);

        /*THE BAR IS PLACED IN THE JFRAME WINDOW*/
        this.setJMenuBar(bar);
        /*THE MENU IS ADDED TO THE BAR*/
        bar.add(menu);

        /*THE ITEMS ARE ADDED TO THE MENU*/        
        menu.add(connect);
        menu.add(create);
        menu.add(exit);

        /*MAKE ITEMS LISTEN TO THE EVENT FROM THE CODE CLASSES*/
        create.addActionListener(servidor);
        connect.addActionListener(cliente);        

        exit.addActionListener(servidor);
        exit.addActionListener(cliente);

        botonchat.addActionListener(cliente);
        botonchat.addActionListener(servidor);



        /*CREATING THE LAYOUTS*/
        /*AREACHAT*/
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        this.add(scroll, gbc);

        /*TEXTFIELD*/

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        this.add(campochat,gbc);


       /*BOTON*/ 

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;

        this.add(botonchat, gbc);

        this.setVisible(true);


    }


       /*CREATING THE GETTERS AND SETTERS*/

    /*GETTERS*/
       public JTextArea  getAreachat(){        

           return areachat;         
    }

       public JMenuItem getCreate(){


           return create;
       }


       public JMenuItem getConnect(){

           return connect;

       }
      public JTextField getTextField(){

          return campochat;
      }

      public JButton getButton(){

          return botonchat;

      }

      /*SETTERS*/

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        Gui objeto = new Gui();

    }     

}
```

Here is the log of errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at backend.Server.writeLine(Server.java:80)
    at backend.Server.actionPerformed(Server.java:48)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 58 seconds)
```

Comment: Dear Friend, the questions are shown to users on the basis of tags, not the capitalism. If you have included the tag Java, it will be visible to all the users who are more active in Java field. There is technically no need of writing it in all caps to make more visible. And why I commented is because, if you come for an interview to me for Java programmer and you have written JAVA in your resume, I will just kick you a$$. You should know how to write. ALVARO.

Comment: if you talk to me about "capitalism" when referring to "capital" letters I will send you to a primary Soviet school for learning the difference. And yes, the larger the letters are, the more visible they are.

Comment: Why don't you accompany me, so that you could learn words are written in capital when they are an acronyms, not for more visibility.

Comment: when they are acronyms, letters are separated by dots.

Comment: Check how many of them have letters separated by dots http://www.acronymfinder.com/ and just shut up now kid, I have work to do.

Comment: this is like misspelling, you mix up capitalism with capital letters, dont be surprised that people miss the dots like you also do buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite my whole answer:

Your code have several implementation flaws that make it difficult to read, debug and generate error.

The `NullPointerException` you get is because you are setting two `ActionListener` on the `send` button (a listener for `Client` and a listener for `Server`):

```
botonchat.addActionListener(cliente);
botonchat.addActionListener(servidor);
```

So no matter if you only set up variable for `Server` or `Client`, both will be called,  one will have some `null` variables -> `NullPointerException`.

A quick (and dirty) fix would be to check if the variable `oos` is set before using it and to clear the `JTextField` only when the data have been read:

```
//Server
public void writeLine(String linea)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.oos != null)
        {
            oos.writeObject(linea);
            servertalkstogui.getTextField().setText("");//clearing JTextField
            servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append("\n I say: " + linea);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}


//Client
public void writeLine(String linea)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.oos != null)
        {
            // to send it to the server
            oos.writeObject(linea);
            clienttalkstogui.getTextField().setText("");//clear the text when it have been read
            // to have it displayed on the client window too
            clienttalkstogui.getAreachat().append(linea);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // this.closeClient();
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

Remove the clearing of the `JTextField` in `actionPerformed`:

```
//Server
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if (ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getCreate()/* .getButton() */)
    {
        servertalkstogui.getAreachat().append("This is the server: " + "\n");
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    if (ae.getSource() == servertalkstogui.getButton())
    {
        String linea = servertalkstogui.getTextField().getText();
        //servertalkstogui.getTextField().setText("");// do not clear the text here ! You don't know if it will be read yet. 

        this.writeLine(linea);
    }
}
```

This work without any `Exception`.

A good practice is to separate the code of `Client` and `Server`: there is no reason to instantiate both in the `Gui`.

Comment: My mistake, I should have used `synchronized` block.

Comment: Did you tried to debug it ? Does it goes into the run method ? Which line of code freezes exactly ?

Comment: Gohead, I will try to run it if I have the chance

Comment: The edited code works. But I see that you will face the same problem with your client code because it tries to use variable before they get initialized.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant watch the video right now. But your code never use the Client class, plus the error stack you post specifically sport the error on the Server, not on the client. Try to run my code tell me how it goes.

Comment: J'ai visionner la video et modifier ma reponse. J'espere que cela va regler ton problème :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the important thing to find out, ! that the issue was because both client and server were activated because both pointed to the same button despite having different variables both would be activated but one would have no oos content! brilliant to have found out! thank you again! I have only been in java for 10 days, and I learn watching youtube videos.